# Unit Testing promise in service in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

i am trying to unit test the below function :

```js
   Service.test = function(id) {
    return this.getDetails(id).then(function (details){

          return "name";    
    });
   };
```

So far i have tried it by myself and done the following thing:

```js
describe(
   'TempServ',
    function() {
 var TempSer, $httpBackend, $q, CapabilityService;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_TempServ_, _$httpBackend_, _$q_,
     _CapabilityService_) {
  TempServ = _TempServ_;
  $q = _$q_;
  $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  CapabilityService = _CapabilityService_;
   }));

 it(" should be in Pending state",function() {
  spyOn(TemplateService, 'getDetails').and.callThrough();
  console.log(TemplateService.test());
      
 });

    });
```

I want something, that can mock the getDetails and i can return what i want instead what really would be returned and test function to work by itself fully .
Only the getDetails to be mocked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something like this

```
spyOn(TemplateService, 'getDetails').and.returnValue($q.when('mockDetails'));
$rootScope.$digest();
```

This will allow you to make a test like the following:

```
it('should be in pending state', function(done) {
  spyOn(TemplateService, 'getDetails').and.returnValue($q.when('mockDetails'));


  TemplateService.test().then(function(result) {
    expect(result).toBe('name'); // this could also be a value computed with "mockDetails"
    done();
  });

  $rootScope.$digest();
});
```

Comment: I tried, its working!! thanks :) 
i will bug you for further questions if i get any , ok ?

Answer (score 1):

```
spyOn(TemplateService, 'getDetails').and.callThrough();
```

This line will execute the actual implementation of getDetails in a spy context. You can use something like

```
spyOn(TemplateService, 'getDetails').and.returnValue(true)
```

instead. If you want to test what happens inside the callback, usually you need to manually trigger a digest cycle update via $scope.$apply();